# How can I assign win-e to open my home folder?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, shortcuts

In 11.10, I want to customize keyboard shortcuts. Especially, I want to assign <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> for opening the home folder with nautilus. (If I can open a specific folder other than the home folder, it is better.) I opened the keyboard setting, and I see the following window:

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

What do all these mean? I have a shortcut for `Home folder` with the key stroke `Explorer`. What is `Explorer`? How can I customize?

If I want to assign a shortcut for opening a directory (say, document directory) with nautilus, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Explorer` key stroke can be found in some laptops if you want to open home folder by nautilus this shortcut will not help you because it will open using thunder file manager 
so click custom shortcut and press `+` then in the enter a name you want and in the command write this `nautilus /home/<your username>` or any directory instead

then choose a shortcut to it by clicking `Disable` then stroke the key that you want to be a shortcut from keyboard

it will work

Comment: I tries this. My `command` is `nautilus /home/snooc` but it does not work. The shortcut says `Super+E` .. any guess why it won't work?

Answer (score 12):

In the Keyboard window, on the Shortcuts tab, select the line that says Home folder and hit Enter. Then input your shortcut: win+e

[image]